# Unable to Assign return of a function to a variable in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift3

I have the date being returned from the function `today()` as an Int. But I want to assign this value to the variable `theDate` as an integer. Here is my code:

The following is simply to get the date:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let date = NSDate()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
let calendar = NSCalendar.current
```

Now I do stuff to this to isolate the date number. For some reason I have to do this in a function. So here that is:

```
 func today() -> Int {
    let x: Int = calendar.component(.day, from: date as Date)
    return x
}
```

But now when I do `let theDate = today()` it gives an error

How do I assign it to the variable `theDate`?

If you don't know of a solution related to the method above, any other method that puts today's date as an integer in a variable is ok too because that's what I want. I am using Swift 3.

Comment: You'll find more similar questions with answers with a search for `[swift] property initializers run before 'self' is available`.

Comment: Another related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651085/instance-member-cannot-be-used-on-type-of-custom-class

Comment: @NiravD when I do what is written in that page, it doesn't work either.

Comment: @PallavAgarwal It is like this way `var x: Int {
         return self.today()
    }`

Comment: Ahhh. Got it thanks!