# property initializers run before 'self' is available error Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api

I have a SearchURL String which gets a *chose* variable from previous view controller. And with this gotten variable, SearchURL should be used in callAlamo func. But I have an error:

[image]

Should I use async dispatch or something like this? I've tried many things like putting everything in viewDidLoad() but did not work. Anybody could help?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651085/instance-member-cannot-be-used-on-type-of-custom-class.

Comment: @MartinR I have seen. Did not help.

Comment: @MartinR For the record man, not a duplicate of those 3 questions. His question was more about passing values across VCs (and then initializing properties, which those questions address) *plus* a tricky string bug in it. BTW, his issue was completely solved :)

Comment: @PauloMattos: For the record: Everything I can see in the *question* is a *compiler error* due to an instance property whose initial value depends on another property. The various possible solutions (lazy variable, computed property, move initialisation to a method) are all contained in the answers of above threads. – I *may* be that the real problem was something else, but then that information is not contained in the question (and the question therefore unclear).

Comment: @MartinR Anyway bro, he is a rookie coder -- we all been there :) He can't (yet!) fix his issue by looking at related questions -- he needs *hands on* help with his code (and English isn't his first language, making matters worse). No need to scary him away from SO... let's help him up the ladder together :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewDidLoad` will not be called *everytime* you enter your view controller, as such, you may not detect updates to the `chosed` property (among other tricky issues).

You could do it in `viewWillAppear` method instead:

```
var SearchURL: String!

overide func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    SearchURL = "...\(chosed!)..."
    ...
}
```

Or you could use a *lazy* variable:

```
lazy var SearchURL = {
    return "...\(self.chosed!)..."
}()
```

Or use a *computed property* as suggested by Connor Neville below.

Comment: does not help: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}

Comment: @belab Answer updated!

Comment: Still same error : (

Comment: @belab Don't use `viewDidLoad` for this, see my answer for details. Do it in the `viewWillAppear` method instead.

Comment: I put SearchURL, selectedItem.text, and callAlamo func in viewWillAppear, instead of viewDidLoad. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}

Comment: @belab Try using `"...\(chosed!)..."`, in other words, *unwrap* your optional property.

Comment: I put everything in viewDidLoad, and added SearchURL as a variable with return String. And this "...\(chosed!)..." helped! Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **computed property** like so:

```
var searchURL: String {
   return "https://theurlIcantcopybecauseitsascreenshot.com/\(chosed!)"
}
```

Note that this will be recomputed every time you access it, so if `chosed` changes, so will `searchURL`. You can also make it an implicitly unwrapped optional like in Paulo Mattos' answer, or you could make an initializer that takes `chosed` as a parameter (see comments below, for a caveat). Then you could set `searchURL` in `init`.

Also, just a nitpick to let you know, Swift standard is to have variables in camel case (`searchURL` instead of `SearchURL`).

Comment: Also a nice answer :) The initializer suggestion is ok, but might not be possible if he is creating the `UIViewController` from the storyboard.

Comment: @PauloMattos definitely true. One of the reasons I prefer creating them programmatically :)

Comment: For the record: Now I think I like yours better than mine, haha :) Upvoted!